# ошибка AsyncTask(android)

Tags: android

возникла проблема с AsyncTask не могу понять, как исправить вылет программы после загрузки картинки на сервер. Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
String ClientToken;
    public class FilesUploadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    // Конец строки
    private String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    // Два тире
    private String twoHyphens = "--";
    // Разделитель
    private String boundary =  "----WebKitFormBoundary9xFB2hiUhzqbBQ4M";

    // Переменные для считывания файла в оперативную память
    private int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    private byte[] buffer;
    private int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    // Путь к файлу в памяти устройства
    private String filePath;

    // Адрес метода api для загрузки файла на сервер
    public static final String API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH = "http://91.226.82.163:8000/api/v1/gallery/checklog/";

    // Ключ, под которым файл передается на сервер
    public static final String FORM_FILE_NAME = "photo";

    public FilesUploadingTask(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Результат выполнения запроса, полученный от сервера
        String result = null;

        try {
            // Создание ссылки для отправки файла
            URL uploadUrl = new URL(API_FILES_UPLOADING_PATH);

            // Создание соединения для отправки файла
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uploadUrl.openConnection();

            // Разрешение ввода соединению
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            // Разрешение вывода соединению
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            // Отключение кеширования
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Задание запросу типа POST
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Задание необходимых свойств запросу
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token " + ClientToken);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

            // Создание потока для записи в соединение
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            // Формирование multipart контента

            // Начало контента
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // Заголовок элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                    FORM_FILE_NAME + "\"; filename=\"" + filePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            // Тип данных элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
            // Конец заголовка
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // Поток для считывания файла в оперативную память
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Считывание файла в оперативную память и запись его в соединение
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            // Конец элемента формы
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Получение ответа от сервера
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            // Закрытие соединений и потоков
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
            Log.i("MSG" , connection.getRequestMethod());
            // Считка ответа от сервера в зависимости от успеха
            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                result = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
            } else {
                result = readStream(connection.getErrorStream());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Считка потока в строку
    public String readStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
new FilesUploadingTask(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir()+"/saved.jpg").execute();
```

Error:

> 06-18 21:24:46.068 32032-32293/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer, PID: 32032
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                            at java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:78)
>                                                                                            at java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:72)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu1$FilesUploadingTask.readStream(Menu1.java:225)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu1$FilesUploadingTask.doInBackground(Menu1.java:207)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu1$FilesUploadingTask.doInBackground(Menu1.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)

Comment: `ResponseCode` какой, 201? Все коды 2ХХ являются успешными и тело ответа нужно читать из `connection.getInputStream()`. А в error stream может (но не обязательно) быть передано пояснение к ошибке при кодах 400 и выше.

Comment: @woesss код 201, все правильно

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему, проблема была в строчке:

```
if(serverResponseCode == 200)
```

Правильно было указать

```
if(serverResponseCode == 201)
```